# How to stop loop in cypress

Tags: loops, automated-tests, break, cypress

I have a loop checking 40 items.
I want to stop my loop, when I am finding the first element, which > 0 
This is my code

var genArr = Array.from({ length: 40 }, (v, k) => k + 1);

```
cy.wrap(genArr).each((index) => {
    cy.get('.list-item').eq(index - 1).find('.number')
        .invoke('text')
        .then(text => {
            const pendingCount = text;
            cy.get('.list-item').eq(index - 1).click();
            cy.get('.list-table').find('.list-table-list-item')
                .should('have.length', pendingCount);
            if (text > 0) break
         });
    });
```

});

But I have a syntax error. Help me pls, How can I break my loop

Comment: [https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early)

Comment: I am tried it, but have a error again
if(text > 0) return false;
Error: CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: 'false'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`break` works only for native `for`/`while` loops.

To exit early from an `.each` loop (as was suggested in the comments), the `false` must be returned from the same callback you pass to it, so returning `false` from the nested `then` callback won't have an effect.

You can't even set a flag in the `then` callback and check it in the `each` callback, because `.each()` command is deep down just a `jQuery.fn.each` --- it's synchronous and by the time you'd set up the flag, all iterations will have run (and enqueued the nested commands).

Thus, the only option is not to use `.each()`, and use some kind of recursive command. Let's build one.

```js
function walk ( arr, cb, index = 0 ) {
    if ( !arr.length ) return;
    arr = arr.slice();
    const ret = cb(index, arr.shift());
    ((ret && ret.chainerId) ? ret : cy.wrap(ret))
        .then( ret => {
            if ( ret === false ) return;
            return walk(arr, cb, index + 1);
        });
}

/**
 * Your callback should return/yield `false` if the loop is to exit early.
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('eachSeries', { prevSubject: 'optional' }, (subject, arr, cb) => {

    return subject
        // assume `arr` to be `cb`
        ? walk(subject, arr)
        : walk(arr, cb);
});
```

usage:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.document().then(doc => {
            doc.body.innerHTML = `
                <div class="list-item">0</div>
                <div class="list-item">1</div>
                <div class="list-item">2</div>
                <div class="list-item">3</div>
            `;
        });

        var genArr = Array.from({ length: 40 }, (v, k) => k + 1);

        // the command can be chained on an existing subject
        cy.wrap(genArr).eachSeries((index) => {
            return cy.get('.list-item').eq(index)
                .invoke('text')
                .then(text => {
                    if (text > 1) return false;
                });
        });

        // or it can start the chain (the array is passed as 1st arg)
        cy.eachSeries(genArr, (index) => {
            return cy.get('.list-item').eq(index)
                .invoke('text')
                .then(text => {
                    if (text > 1) return false;
                });
        });

        // you can also return a promise
        cy.eachSeries(['a', 'b', 'c'], (index, value) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(value === 'b' ? false : true);
                }, 500);
            });
        });

        // non-thenable callbacks work too
        cy.eachSeries(['a', 'b', 'c'], (index, value) => {
            return value === 'b' ? false : true;
        });
    });
});
```

In the first two examples above, only the first 3 items are looped through and then the loop exits early.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you very much. Should there be another condition in `walk` like  `if (arr.length === 0) { return; }` to terminate the iteration when the entries in `genArr` are exhausted. I think as is this will infinitely recurse if `false` is never returned from the callback.

Comment: @HakanBaba very good point -- at least infinite recursion results in stack overflow instead of locking up CPU as in iterative infinite loops :). Edited.

Comment: Further edited so that you can return regular promises or even non-thenables from the callback.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you need to drive the test with `genArr`.

The list of 40 items will itself give an 'array-like' subject to which you can apply the `filter()` with a function argument.
Cypress just uses jquery, so refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) for the syntax (not given in Cypress `.filter()` docs).

The filter function should return `true` to include the item, so again we use jquery (Cypress.$) to construct the expression.

Since you want to break after the first non-zero item, we can just chain `.eq(0)`,

```js
it('clicks first item with content not "0"', () => {

  cy.get('.list-item')
    .filter((i, item) => Cypress.$(item).find('.number').text() !== '0')
    .eq(0)
    .click()          // previous line yields list-item so we can now click it
    .find('.number')  // then go further into DOM to get the actual number
    .invoke('text')
    .then(pendingCount => {
      cy.get('.list-table').find('.list-table-list-item')
       .should('have.length', pendingCount);   // Now test the number of table rows
    })

});
```

I tested it with this html fragment, which does not have `onClick()`, just a static table.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="title">Item1</span>
      <span class="number">0</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="title">Item2</span>
      <span class="number">4</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="title">Item3</span>
      <span class="number">0</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <span class="title">Item4</span>
      <span class="number">2</span>
    </li>
  </main>
</ul>
<div class="list-table">
  <div class="list-table-list-item">Pending1</div>
  <div class="list-table-list-item">Pending2</div>
  <div class="list-table-list-item">Pending3</div>
  <div class="list-table-list-item">Pending4</div>
</div>
```

---

### Alternative selector using :not and :contains

You can also compose jquery `:not` and `:contains` selectors to produce alternative expressions.

For example the following work in my tests

```js
cy.get('.list-item')
  .not(':contains("0")')
  .eq(0)
  .click()
  .find('.number')
  ...etc
```

```js
cy.get('.list-item:not(:contains("0"))')
  .eq(0)
  .click()
  .find('.number')
  ...etc
```

Note it seems that the Cypress `.contains()` command can't be used in this way (to exclude certain values), although that may just be a lack of imagination on my part.

More complicated jquery is going to be harder to debug, so stick with chained Cypress commands where possible (you can hover over the steps in the command log).

I often chain `.then(x => console.log(x))` to help test the test.