# Stopping loop in cypress

Tags: cypress

Please help me i am beginner and having same issue with code where i am getting below error

```
CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
```

my code looks like this ...

```
cy.xpath(LOGOS).then(($ele) => {
        cy.eachSeries($ele.get(), (index) => {
              return cy.xpath(LOGOS).eq(index)enter code here
                .invoke('text')
                .then((text) => {
                  if (text === 'Market') {
                    cy.xpath(LOGOS).eq(index).click();
                    cy.xpath(MKT).invoke('text').then(val=> {if (val>0)
                    return false;
                    }
                  }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Where's `eachSeries` coming from? What's its API? Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819887/927631

Comment: Thanks dwelle, i have referred your answer in the link you shared ,unfortunately i was unable to use that code because of lack of knowledge in recursive function you have written.So i request you to help me by pointing out mistakes in my code.

Comment: Don't know. Not sure what API those commands you're using support. You'd have to at least specify what plugins you're using so that I could try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Best if you supply a reproducible case in its own repo https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-tiny